# convert direct sql to collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection

How we can convert direct SQL query to collection ?

```
SELECT wk_mpauction_winner_data.auction_id, wk_mpauction_winner_data.customer_id, quote_item.created_at AS quote_item_date ,sales_order_item.item_id AS sales_order_item_id , sales_order.state AS order_state
FROM sales_order_item
JOIN sales_order ON sales_order.entity_id= sales_order_item.order_id
JOIN wk_mpauction_winner_data ON wk_mpauction_winner_data.quote_item_id= sales_order_item.quote_item_id
LEFT JOIN quote_item   ON quote_item.item_id= sales_order_item.quote_item_id
LEFT JOIN quote  ON  quote_item.quote_id= quote.entity_id
WHERE quote_item.item_id IS NOT NULL AND quote.customer_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Above query is already converted to collection

Comment: @Rakesh no it is just for example ... my question is short and i add above line  :)

Comment: please share your code so user can help for you

Comment: @Rakesh sql =" select * from quote" ... 
i know for this sql we have collection but if i have custom sql (each sql) how i can do this

Comment: You need to create model class for module and use your model class as factorymethod to get collection of magento

Comment: @Rakesh i think on matgento 1 we can create collection without create model ... thanks i try it